# Can I Do This In Grails 2: Secure Individual Tabs with Spring Security

Tags: security, grails

If I create tabs using one of the Grails GUI options (which one should I use), is it possible to turn tabs on and off, based on the current user? For example only users with a role of admin should see the Manage Users tab. And even anonymous users should see the Main Content tab.

Ideally, I'd like to use Spring Security ACL.

Comment: Glad to have gotten some recent answers to this question that I asked 3 years ago! The title has a new meaning since the release of Grails 2.x. When I wrote the question before, it's was my second "Can I Do This In Grails" question :).

Comment: :) I didn't see the date. Someone must have updated it and it showed up near the top of the list for new grails questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to add, sometimes you can add too much logic and coding in the view (GSP). You can push more of the code to the controller by using other options such as the navigation plugin along with the Spring-Security plugin. The nice thing is the view is just cleaner removing condition tags.

```
grails install-plugin navigation
```

Then in the controller just use the @Secured annotation. For example I created two tabs with two corresponding controllers.

```
@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
class SlidesController {

static navigation = [
    group:'tabs', order:10, title:'Users', action:'index'
]
def index = {
      .....
}

@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
class ProgramsController {

static navigation = [
    group:'tabs', order:10, title:'Programs & Presentation', action:'index'
]
def index = {
      .....
}
```

In the view:

```
<head>
     ... other head elems.
  <nav:resources/>
</head>

<body>
<nav:render/>
    ... Your other stuff
</body>
```

Tabs automatically appears (would be also useful to make this view a layout GSP).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible  and pretty easy with the Acegi (Spring Security Plugin), see [this section of the docs](http://www.grails.org/AcegiSecurity+Plugin+-+Securing+URLs).  You'll need to define some roles, and then describe how those roles apply to different URLS. Example (from link above):

/admin/**=ROLE_USER
/book/test/**=IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY
/book/**=ROLE_SUPERVISOR

There is also explanation about exactly how to do this in Grails In Action book.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This addresses securing URLs. However, requirement is secure specific tabs on the same page.

The prototype of my app (done using ZK which I'm having doubts about) is at http://flashlit.serveall.net/flashlit.

Comment: if by the same page you mean that the HTML used to render all tabs are sent in the same http request, then you are out of luck - the design of your app's security layer needs to be changed so that the secure content dont get sent. 
It is much easier and more modular to segregate by url (and then use ajax to load the tab's content).

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security has a nice tag library for this. You can delimit rendering the tabs by using something similar to this:

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('supervisor')">

This content will only be visible to users who have
the "supervisor" authority in their list of <tt>GrantedAuthority</tt>s.

</sec:authorize>
```

You can just enable the jsp tag as normal:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
```

Read more about it [here if you like](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html)